# Power BI Encoding UTF8 for a column

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, m

I am trying to force an encoding for a column in Power BI to UTF 8, however it is failing with an error.

```
= Table.SelectRows(
  #"Changed Type", 
  each 
    if ([number] is null or [number] = "") then
      null
    else
      Text.FromBinary(Text.ToBinary([number], 1251), TextEncoding.Utf8)
)
```

The `[number]` field is TEXT and contains values like TEST_DAVE, PROD10, test10 .

The error is

Expression.Error: We cannot convert the value "TEST_DAVE" to type Logical.
Details:
Value=TEST_DAVE
Type=[Type]

Tried lots of combinations of this statement but its not working yet ... Any ideas please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Table.SelectRows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/table-selectrows)  function expects a logical true/false result but you're returning nulls and/or text.

Try using [Table.TransformColumns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/table-transformcolumns) instead.

```
= Table.TransformColumns(
    #"Changed Type",
    {
     "number",
     each if (_ = null or _ = "") then null
          else Text.FromBinary(Text.ToBinary(_, 1251), TextEncoding.Utf8)
    }
  )
```